# Uncaught TypeError: Kotlin.defineModule is not a function

Tags: kotlin

I am developing a web app using Kotin for JavaScript and the create-react-kotlin-app CLI. When I pushed my code yesterday everything worked fine. But when I started it up again today I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Kotlin.defineModule is not a function
    at C:\src\main\kotlin\kotlinext\js\Object.kt:20
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\src\main\kotlin\kotlinext\js\Object.kt:20)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\my_workspace\bwa-js\webpack\bootstrap e6d8ae87c0ef02bf2708:678)
    at fn (C:\my_workspace\bwa-js\webpack\bootstrap e6d8ae87c0ef02bf2708:88)
    at Object.map../index/index.css (C:\src\ui\tabbar\workout\changeWorkout\ChangeWorkoutPage.kt:90)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\my_workspace\bwa-js\webpack\bootstrap e6d8ae87c0ef02bf2708:678)
    at fn (C:\my_workspace\bwa-js\webpack\bootstrap e6d8ae87c0ef02bf2708:88)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\my_workspace\bwa-js\stream.kt:137)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\my_workspace\bwa-js\webpack\bootstrap e6d8ae87c0ef02bf2708:678)
    at module.exports (C:\my_workspace\bwa-js\webpack\bootstrap e6d8ae87c0ef02bf2708:724)
    at C:\my_workspace\bwa-js\webpack\bootstrap e6d8ae87c0ef02bf2708:724
```

Yesterday everything was working fine and nothing has changed in my code. I did a `git status` to make sure.

Below is the file that the error is coming from. I've marked the line with a comment. It is the 3rd before the last line.

```
package ui.tabbar.workout.changeWorkout

import external.onsenui.Ons
import external.onsenui.OnsNav
import kotlinext.js.js
import kotlinx.html.style
import model.Workout
import react.RBuilder
import react.dom.div
import service.state.WorkoutStateService

private lateinit var navigator: OnsNav

fun RBuilder.changeWorkoutPage(_navigator: OnsNav) {
  navigator = _navigator
  Ons.Page {
    attrs {
      key = "ChangeWorkoutPage"
      renderToolbar = this@changeWorkoutPage.renderToolbar
    }
    Ons.List {
      attrs {
        dataSource = WorkoutStateService.workouts.toTypedArray()
        renderRow = renderListItem
      }
    }
  }
}

private val RBuilder.renderToolbar: Function<Any>
  get() = {
    Ons.Toolbar {
      attrs {
        modifier = "material"
      }
      div("left") {
        Ons.BackButton {
          attrs {
            onClick = {
              navigator.popPage()
            }
          }
        }
      }
      div("center") {
        attrs {
          style = js {
            textAlign = "center"
          }
        }
        +"Workouts"
      }
      div("right") {
        Ons.Icon {
          //placeholder to center text in the center div
        }
      }
    }
  }

private val RBuilder.renderListItem
  get() = { row: Workout, index: Int ->
    Ons.ListItem {
      attrs {
        key = row.name + index
        className = "workoutDaysListItem"
        tappable = true
        onClick = {
          setCurrentWorkout(row)
          navigator.popPage()
        }
      }
      Ons.Card {
        attrs {
          className = "workoutDaysListCard"
        }
        div("innerWorkoutDaysListCard") {
          div {
            +row.name
          }
          div {
            +"${row.dayList.size} days"
          }
        }

      }
    }
  }

private val setCurrentWorkout = { workout: Workout -> //The error is here
  WorkoutStateService.currentWorkout = workout
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Gradle? If that's the case could you try disabling [build cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html)?

Comment: @AntonBannykh No I am using create-react-kotlin-app and Yarn. I found on the create-react-kotlin-app github page that I need to delete the cache in node_modules. I haven't been able to try it yet but I will be able to tonight. And considering how the error showed up out of nowhere with no code changes it sound like the cache could be the problem.

Comment: Good luck, hope that'll fix it! My hunch is you might have ended up mixing regular compilation output and minimized kotlin.js standard library (result of DCE application). That could could be due to some faulty caching, as well as a number of other options =)

Comment: That very well could have been it. This didn't start happening until I did a production build. I ended up having to clear the cache in node_modules and the browser cache to get it working. Clearing just the node_modules cache didn't work. Which is surprising since I'm using chrome with dev tools open and the "don't use cache" option checked. I am using localhost as the hostname though so I'm not sure if that had something to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer here https://github.com/JetBrains/create-react-kotlin-app#npm-start-or-yarn-start

Which said to delete the `.cache` folder in `node_modules`. I had to do one more step though which was to clear my browser cache.

Even though I was using Chrome with dev tools open and the "don't use cache" option checked, I still had to manually clear the cache.